# Are SoundCloud track id's guaranteed to be ascending over time?

Tags: api, soundcloud

I am fetching several sets of tracks and combining them into one single array that I want to sort by the `created_with` field, i.e. most recent tracks first.

However, since all I want is the date order of these track, a much simpler sort would be to use the `id` field. Can I make the assumption that higher id's means more recent track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is important then I wouldn't do it, because this is not defined anywhere and could change in the future.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I should go the non-lazy way and actually compare the dates then :)